# Trying to change color of label through an array which doesn't work?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a loop to check if certain files exist, and if they do they're going to change an indicator label on my form, but I can't seem to work out how to do this w/out typing out every single one manually such as this:

```
        if (File.Exists("C:\\MonitorFiles\\BOT-PC-8is1.txt"))
        {
            PC8IS1.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        if (File.Exists("C:\\MonitorFiles\\BOT-PC-8is2.txt"))
        {
            PC8IS2.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        if (File.Exists("C:\\MonitorFiles\\BOT-PC-8is3.txt"))
        {
            PC8IS3.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
```

I've tried several very basic ways of just building arrays and substituting but I can't put " VariableX.backcolor ", I've tried [variable].backcolor, no dice.

This is a hard one to search for on google, and hopefully has an easy answer!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a dictionary, the key will be the file-name the value will be your control.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Dictionary<string, Label> files;
    public Form1()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();
        files = new Dictionary<string,Label>();
        files.Add("C:\\MonitorFiles\\BOT-PC-8is1.txt", PC8IS1);
        files.Add("C:\\MonitorFiles\\BOT-PC-8is2.txt", PC8IS2);
        files.Add("C:\\MonitorFiles\\BOT-PC-8is3.txt", PC8IS3);
     }
    public void otherFunc()
    {
        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            if (File.Exists(item.Key))
                item.Value.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make an array (or list) of your labels, as well:

```
private List<Label> labels = new List<Label> 
{ 
    PC8IS1, 
    PC8IS2,
    PC8IS3,
    // ...
};
```

Then, in your method:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;++i)
{
    if (File.Exists(@"C:\MonitorFiles\BOT-PC-8is" + i.ToString() + ".txt"))
        labels[i].BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<Control, Color>> filesAndColors = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<Control, Color>>();
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, KeyValuePair<Control, Color>> kvp in filesAndColors) 
{
    if(File.Exists(kvp.Key))
        kvp.Value.Key.BackColor = kvp.Value.Value;
}
```

Where the first Key here is the name of the file to look for, and then second key (Value.Key) would be the control you want to change the color for, and the final value would be your color.